# Specify the user for Xen's xm console?

Tags: console, xen

I have a situation where I need `xm console <domID>` to drop into a specific user in a CentOS PV VM, say UserB. UserA was the first user created in the VM, and whenever I `xm console <domID>` I get UserA.  I tried deleting UserA but then get the following when I connect:

> User not known to the underlying
>   authentication module

How can I change the user which `xm console <domID>` connects to?

Looking online, most of the serial console tweaks for CentOS are in grub. I'm using the kernel line in the config and therefore am not using grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have an autologin set in /etc/inittab

Can you post it here?

Comment: Good call, I didn't think of inittab.  Here's the line: `co:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -n -l /usr/local/sbin/autologin xvc0 9600 vt100-nav`  I assume I can drop the autologin and have it yield a login prompt?